# Change image on active parent div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this code in which the image changes when a parent div is in an active state but it how to undo it when I click it again? How to bring back the original image? I tried putting return false at the end but it didn't work

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card egg" data-img="https://data.imgtools.co/output/tool/preview/400x400/face-extractor.png">
 <div class="card-image">
  <img src="https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/IeNJWoKYx1waOhfWF6TiuSiWBLfqLb18lmZYXSgsH1fvb8v1IYiZr5aYWe0Gxu-pVZX3"/>
 </div>
</div>
```

```
$('.egg').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  var new_src = $(this).attr('data-img');
  $(".card-image img").attr("src",new_src);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep track of the current img src before toggling its state, overwriting the same data attribute you use to store the alternative image.

In this demo I also better dealt with the selector you used to fetch the img element, restricting its action only to the img child embedded in the clicked .egg div:

```js
$('.egg').click(function() {  
  const new_src = $(this).attr('data-img');  
  const curr_src = $(this).find('.card-image img').attr('src');
  $(this).attr('data-img', curr_src);
  
  $(this).toggleClass("active");  
  $(this).find('.card-image img').attr("src", new_src);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="card egg" data-img="https://data.imgtools.co/output/tool/preview/400x400/face-extractor.png">
  <div class="card-image">
    <img src="https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/IeNJWoKYx1waOhfWF6TiuSiWBLfqLb18lmZYXSgsH1fvb8v1IYiZr5aYWe0Gxu-pVZX3" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly but when I try it with my code then it doesn't work. Is it due to the input field? [link](https://jsfiddle.net/taymurisrar/861eg2h5/)

Comment: I slightly changed your fiddle using a more relaxed selector for the inner image and added a preventDefault on top of the handler to avoid the event to trigger multiple times. This is the code working https://jsfiddle.net/ke2c4qvt/ (I also added a css rule that show a smaller image for the sake of having more space to deal with the code)